# Float DIV without fix height

Tags: css, css-float

Some basic css-float question, I wasn't able to solve it myself so I would be grateful for any help.

I want to float 3 container left and 3 right - thats all. The containers' height is set by it's content.

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 26px;
    background-color: #6abe0f;
    width: 416px;
    color: #3e3e3e;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 26px;
    background-color: #6abe0f;
    width: 416px;
    color: #3e3e3e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hausmaster/TZhWy/5/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the problem in fiddle..divs are floated left and right only..What problem you are facing..

Comment: Do you want the divs that are floated right and left to stack on top of each other with no white space?

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex IF he needs like that there is no need of margin-top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.float-left { clear: left; }`.

http://jsfiddle.net/TZhWy/6/

Or put them into rows and then use `overflow:hidden;`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="float-left>I go left</div>
  <div class="float-right>I go right</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TZhWy/8/

Comment: Thanks! But how to make the space between the DIV on the right hand side equal to the space of the DIVs on the left side? :)

Comment: Do you mean how to make them the same height??  Easiest way set a `min-height`.  E.g. .float-right, .float-left { min-height: 250px; }. http://jsfiddle.net/TZhWy/9/

Comment: No - the distance between Left #1 and Left #2 is 26px because of the margin.
The distance between Right #1 and Right #2 is way bigger. How to make the distance between Right #1, #2 and #3 also 26px?

Comment: That sounds a lot like the link I just gave in the comment above.

Comment: In the link above it looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/a2yelb4yb/ (at least on my notebook)
Left #2 is right, not left. As soon I make Right #1 higher Left #2 floats left.

Comment: When I click on my JSFIDDLE link, it loads jsfiddle and displays correctly.  Not sure I can help anymore

Comment: Oh may bad! Sorry.. Clicked wrong link. Works like charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this one,insert divider div in each row

```
<div class="divider"></div>

.divider {
    width:832px;
    float:left;
    height:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TZhWy/7/